# Function sent 3 as an integer receives 51 that is a decimal value of "3" char

Tags: c++, excel, vba, function

I'm creating a .dll library in C/C++ for VBA. It will contain functions for communication via RS232 serial port and data will be processed in Excel.

I have 2 functions. One for writing to port one for reading.

When I sending a port number e.g. 3 from VBA to one of them, doesn´t matter which one and print it exactly after it was received by function it shows decimal value of 3 that is correct.
When I send the same variable that consists number 3 to second one, function receive 51 that is a decimal value of "3" char.

So at first VBA sends integer then it changes and sends decimal value of "3" char. There is no code before printing received variable in my functions that can change value.

Here is simplified code of my functions.

```
int __stdcall PortRead(short int & Port){
   printf("%d   %c\n",Port,Port);
   return 0;
}

int __stdcall PortWrite(short int & Port, BSTR & Message){
   printf("%d   %c\n",Port,Port);
   return 0;
}
```

VBA code:

```vb
Declare Function PortRead Lib "rs232_r.dll" (ByRef x As Integer) As Integer
Declare Function PortWrite Lib "rs232_w.dll" (ByRef x As Integer, ByRef y As String) As Integer
Dim Message As String
Dim PortNumber As Integer

Sub Example()
PortNumber = 3
Message = ":trac:data?"
aa = PortWrite(PortNumber, Message)
Debug.Print aa
xx = PortRead(PortNumber)
Debug.Print xx
End Sub
```

As I said, passed values will be different when I'm sending one variable to 2 functions but when I change it like the next example both functions will receive the same correct value.

```vb
Declare Function PortRead Lib "rs232_r.dll" (ByRef x As Integer) As Integer
Declare Function PortWrite Lib "rs232_w.dll" (ByRef x As Integer, ByRef y As String) As Integer
Dim Message As String
Dim PortNumber1 As Integer
Dim PortNumber2 As Integer
Dim Number As Integer

Sub Example()
Number = 3
PortNumber1 = Number
PortNumber2 = Number
Message = ":trac:data?"
aa = PortWrite(PortNumber1, Message)
Debug.Print aa
xx = PortRead(PortNumber2)
Debug.Print xx
End Sub
```

Comment: The return value type declaration is wrong.  It is Long, not Integer.  Unlikely to be the cause of the problem.  Do favor Long for the arguments as well, passed ByVal instead of ByRef.

Comment: The question described in the text (portnum has changed) is not the same as the question illustrated in the code (function does not return zero).  If indead you meant that portnum had changed, please correct code to show "debug.print portnum"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA try changing `ByRef` to `ByVal`

Answer (score 0):

The code posted maps "integer = int" and "integer = short int". Which is it? (Ar you compiling 32bit cpp or 64bit cpp?).

Excel will repair the stack if your declarations are invalid, and Excel will not crash, so you should not depend on crashing Excel to find invalid declarations.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a C++ function from VBA ByRef, you might expect to receive a reference in the C++ function, like

```
short int & Port
```

But ByRef in VBA means "ByPointer" in C++.

Answer (score -2):

So I found an issue. As you suggested I took closer look on parameters sent to function ByRef. After few experiments I discovered my mistake. I sent a number to function by reference that means I sent only address of memory not a value. Then my first function made few calculations because of conversion to char and creating string and saved a new changed value because of calculations to previous memory address. So when I was sending variable to second function also by reference, the value saved on memory address was already changed by my first function. So I was rewriting value of variable by myself. I should apology to Microsoft for my rude words that I said about its products while I was solving this problem. :) Thanks mates

Comment: If the answer from @cyboashu has helped you then please consider accepting it instead of duplicating it.